# Swift. UILabel text alignment

Tags: enums, uilabel, swift

I create my UILabel in swift:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect( x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 50))
```

setting properties seems to be easy:

```
label.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

How to implement enum types like textAlignment?
In Objective C it was

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

but in swift it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

These are now `enum`s.

You can do:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center;
```

Or, for shorthand:

```
label.textAlignment = .center;
```

**Swift 3**

```
label.textAlignment = .center
```

Comment: Got it! my mistake was that i was writing .center instead

Comment: Could you link to the documentation ? Since as I can see they had to rewrite those enums from ObjC.

Comment: This answer helped. I tried .Center and it didn't look right. Checked enums and used .Justified and it looked better         enum {
   NSTextAlignmentLeft      = 0,
   NSTextAlignmentCenter    = 1,
   NSTextAlignmentRight     = 2,
   NSTextAlignmentJustified = 3,
   NSTextAlignmentNatural   = 4,
};

Answer (score 2):

Enums in Swift are different than they are in Objective-C.

What in Objective-C would be `NSTextAlignmentCenter` is in Swift `NSTextAlignment.Center`.

Answer (score 0):

For Centre use, `myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center`